# how to use docker bridge network on google cloud platform?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I can't use the following ways to open website with hostip:8000:

```
docker network create -d bridge mybridge 

docker run -d --net mybridge --name db redis 
docker run -d --net mybridge -e DB=db -p 8000:5000 --name web chrch/web
```

I have build gpu VM instance without docker images and install docker by myself

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide `docker ps` output.

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a network?  You can run two containers on one VM and they will be able to communicate with each other.  The biggest issue you face is being able to connect to port 8000 from outside GCP.  For that, you can use an ssh tunnel for development.

Comment: docker ps has two running container, and there are no abnormal things

Comment: I have open 8000 in firewall rules and whether it is the same with ssh tunnel ?

Answer (score 0):

These steps should solve your problem

- Check with `docker ps`  that your containers are running
- Check if firewall in GCP console. If port 8000 is open ( if no open for your ip )
- Check  GCP console  your VM's Public IP and try with that

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work. But following ways work, I don't know why:docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx